# Understanding "雪の色はそこまで行かぬうちに"

Tags: translation, reading-comprehension

Consider

> もうそんな寒さかと島村は外を眺めると、鉄道の官舎らしいバラックが山裾に寒々と
> 散らばっているだけで、
> **雪の色はそこまで行かぬうちに**闇に呑まれていた。

which apparently means

> When Shimamura gazed outside, thinking it had already gotten cold, railroad
> residence-like barracks were desolately dispersed at the foot of the mountains, and
> before the snow hues could reach that far, the barracks were swallowed by
> darkness.

I'm having trouble parsing "雪の色はそこまで行かぬうちに". What does うち mean in this context, and how is it being used with the 連体形 before it to form the meaning of "before the snow hues could reach that far"?

Comment: Related: [What does the うち in ならないうちに mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4824/5010) うち basically means "while", and the sentence means "The color of snow, **while** it does not reach that far, has been swallowed by darkness".

Comment: FYI. I vaguely remember reading somewhere that Seidenstecker made (arguably) similar mistakes (wrong subject) in a bunch of places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

雪の色はそこまで行かぬうちに has the same structure as 花子が学校に着かないうちに = *before Hanako reaches the school*. Thus it means *before the color of snow goes that far*.

I think it is a matter of interpretation, but the part resonates with the beginning

> 国境の長いトンネルを抜けると雪国であった。夜の底が白くなった。

So it is late in the evening, and the scenery Shimamura is seeing is colored white at bottom. He sees barracks in the distance, but the color of snow is already gone around/before there. (This may sound not logical, but I don't think it's surprising in Kawabata's writings.)

---

The translator takes the subject of '闇に吞まれていた' as the barracks. I'd say it is possible, but then it would be definitely more natural to say 雪の色**が**そこまで行かぬうちに.

Comment: In your interpretation, is 雪の色 the subject of both 行く and 呑まれる?

Comment: @YusukeMatsubara I think so, but it could be something like eyesight or visibility (or as the passage of Snow Country is sometimes compared to, 'the camera work').