# Can うちは mean the same thing as うちに?

Tags: grammar, translation

Tell me please in the sentence below, can うちは means the same as うちに? Or it's just うち like "we" ? 
[image]

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The うち(に) means "while/during/before", similar to [間]{あいだ}に. (No. 2 [うち in weblio辞書](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1) or No. 5 [うち in goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/5466/m0u/%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1/).)

> 明るいうちに帰ってきなさい。
> Come home before dark.
>
> 本を読んでるうちに寝てしまった。
> I fell asleep while reading.

The は is the binding particle([係助詞]{かかりじょし}). うちは is like "as long as~" and similar to [間]{あいだ}は. ([うちは in weblio辞書](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%AE%E9%BB%92%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1).)

> おとなしくしているうちは、ここにいてもいい。
> You can stay here as long as you keep quiet.
>
> [双方]{そうほう}(が)[噛]{か}み合っているうちは、[極上]{ごくじょう}の[桃源郷]{とうげんきょう}に[身]{み}を[置]{お}ける。
> The two can stay in paradise (utopia?) as long as they are fighting.

Comment: I am not sure if I can get this in to a comment but I have not seen うち referred to as same as 間　before, altho it is logical (thank you). However I do wonder about うちに：We learn it has two meanings. 1)To do something before a state/situation changes, as in the 1st example, & 2) while a continuous process is happening, another change occurs w/o the volition of the speaker, as in the 2nd example.  I accept うち（は）can be the same as 間 but can うちに？　Like 〜間 & 〜間に、I thought うち　＆　うちに were different. (??)

Comment: @Tim You can also say them as 明るい[間]{あいだ}に帰ってきなさい/本を読んでいる間に寝てしまった/おとなしくしている間はここにいてもいい/双方かみ合っている間は桃源郷に身を置ける, but 間に and うちに are not always interchangeable; you can say 暗くならないうちに帰ってきなさい but not 暗くならない[間]{あいだ}に帰ってきなさい. And the に and は are the case/binding particles, and 間 and うち are nouns, so 間 and 間に / うち and うちに are not the same. (間 / うち can also be used like the conjunctive particles/接続助詞 but they cannot be replaced with 間に/うちに in most cases.)

Comment: @Tim As for 間 vs うち... http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/when-describing-time-span-are-%E9%96%93-%E3%81%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%A0-and-%E5%86%85-%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1-interchangeable22