# When saying "while" doing something, how do: 間、うち and ながら differ?

Tags: grammar, words

I only know aida means a between a space or time and that uchi can only be used with a particle, but other than that, what do these words literally mean , how do you use them and what are the ways they differ?

Answer (score 4):

As for the difference between 間 and うち, see: [When describing time span, are 間 {あいだ} and 内 {うち} interchangeable?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2620/5010)

ながら is used in the following two situations:

1. To emphasize one is making two different actions simultaneously.

   > - 食べながらテレビを見るな。 Don't watch TV while eating.
   > - 走りながらラジオを聞いていました。 I was listening to the radio while running.
2. To mean "despite".

   > - 彼はプロの野球選手でありながら、ピアノも上手だ。
   >     He is good at playing the piano despite being a professional baseball player.
   > - 貧乏ながら幸せに暮らしています。
   >     While I'm in poverty, I'm leading a happy life.

Comment: I believe I learned at some point that ながら constructions require   that the subject of both clauses is the same and 内/間 constructions require that the subjects are different.  Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: @G-Cam I think 間/うち constructions can have a shared subject: 「若い間にいろいろ経験しよう。」「忘れないうちにメモした。」