# Using ていく to express doing something deeply/longer/strongly and tense agreement with ていくうちに

Tags: meaning, tense

While trying to understand how to use ていくうちに in this sentence: (from https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55251/17515)

> 子どもの頃から使っていくうちに、身についてきたものだからです。
>   (The て form) is something we master after using it again and again from childhood.

I found other sentences like this one (from [here](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/605857))

> 考えていくうちに、私は間違いに気付いた
>   While/as I'm thinking further, I noticed that mistake(?)

And the explanation for 考えていくうちに is 'to think longer/to think further'. But then I found this [page](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1427712014) where it says to not use the past tense in the later part after うちに and that that part should express supposition/prediction.

> ○勉強しているうちに、意味がわかった。
>   ×勉強していくうちに、意味がわかった。
>
> ○勉強しているうちに、意味がわかるだろう。
>   ○勉強していくうちに、意味がわかるだろう。

My questions are:
1. Is 考えていくうちに、私は間違いに気付いた incorrect?
2.Does 使っていくう mean 'To use something from now on to the future' or 'using something repeatedly/deeply' like in 考えていく(to think longer/to think further), 見ていく(事情や状況などをまとめたものを確認していくこと), and 確認していく(一つ一つをよく見て確認するさま)

Comment: I don't think 「勉強していくうちに、意味がわかった。」 is incorrect.. (「(もっと深く)勉強していくうちに、意味がわかっ**てき**た。」 might sound more natural, though)