# noun +うちに and noun+間に

Tags: grammar, words, usage, time

When 間【あいだ】に and うちに are preceded by nouns, are they always interchangeable? For example, in 春【はる】休【やす】みのあいだに/うちに友達【ともだち】と一緒【いっしょ】に出掛【でか】けたい。 And also in: 大学生【だいがくせい】のうちに/間【あいだ】に留学【りゅうがく】する。

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2620/5010

Answer (score 2):

Taken directly from the Dictionary of Japanese Grammar here at https://core6000.neocities.org/dojg/ :

> "When it indicates an interval of time, *aida* refers to the 'time space' between two points, i.e., the beginning and the end. In other words, the time space indicated by *aida* can be measured in clocktime. *Uchi*, however, does not refer to such measurable time space; it simply means 'time space within'. Thus, in a situation where a mother wants to read books while her child is away at school, either *uchi* or *aida* can be used. However, in a situation where we want to play tennis before it rains, we cannot substitute *aida* for *uchi*, because it is impossible to specify a time boundary."

It then goes on to give the following example sentences (the asterisks mark what is incorrect):

> 子供が学校に行っている**うちに**/**間に**本を読みます。
>
> (I read books while my child is away at school.)
>
> 雨が降らない**うちに**/***間に**テニスをします。
>
> (I'll go and play tennis before it rains.)
>
> 冷たい**うちに**/***間に**ビールを飲んでください。
>
> (Please drink the beer while it is cold.)

So the answer is no. They are not always interchangeable but in many cases they are.