# Can I replace うちに with 間に in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, nuances

> 日の下を歩いてる**うちに**、耳鳴りがしてきた

Would there be any difference in the nuance?

I have searched between the differences of nuances and this sentence doesn't seem like the meaning would particularly change if I replaced it, but I may be really wrong.

Comment: Possible dup https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68841/45489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace うち with 間 in that sentence.

> 日の下を歩いてる間に、耳鳴りがしてきた。

中上級を教える人のための日本語ガイドブック says:

> ◆「〜うちに」は「〜あいだに」と似た表現ですが、二つの用法に分けて考える必要があります。
>
> ①「ＰうちにＱ」のＱが意志的な動作である場合
> (8) 妻が出掛けている**うちに**、光子に電話をかけた。
> (9) 明るい**うちに**、帰ったほうがいいですよ。
>
> ②「ＰうちにＱ」のＱが無意志的な変化や現象である場合
> (10) おしゃべりに夢中になっている**うちに**、２時間もたってしまった。
> (11) 毎日乗っている**うちに**、運転が上手になります。
>
> ①の用法では、「ＰうちにＱ」には「ＰでないとＱができない（だから、ＰのあいだにＱをする）」というニュアンスが出ます。「ＰあいだにＱ」にはそのようなニュアンスはありません。
> (8)’ 妻が出掛けている**あいだに**、光子に電話をかけた。
> (9)’ 明るい**あいだに**、帰ったほうがいいですよ。
>
> また、「〜うちに」は(12)のように動詞の否定形に後続できますが、「〜あいだに」はできません。
> (12) 暗くならない｛⚪︎うちに／×あいだに｝、帰ったほうがいいですよ。
>
> ②の用法では、「ＰうちにＱ」と「ＰあいだにＱ」に違いはありません。

耳鳴りがする in your sentence is clearly not volitional, and this should make うちに interchangeable with 間に as explained in the last line.

Having said that, though, I personally feel うち sounds more natural not only in your sentence but also in (10) and, especially, (11). 間に sounds to me like you can determine when the event of the main clause (Q) happens or happened. The main clause in (10) can still be understood as a discovery the speaker made at one point of time, but those in (11) and your sentence are both about a gradual change that is correlated with the event of the subordinate clause (P). I feel うち sounds more natural in these cases. But that’s my opinion. There might be regional differences.