# 間 vs 時 vs うち to refer to time intervals

Tags: grammar

So I was considering the grammar points 間に, うちに and 時に today. I came across [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/when-describing-time-span-are-%E9%96%93-%E3%81%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%A0-and-%E5%86%85-%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1-interchangeable,%20and), which talks about 間に vs うちに (which was already in my grammar book).

I'm more curious about the differences between 時に and these constructs. Specifically, today I wanted to make the sentence "I often make mistakes when I write essays". I wrote

> 作文を書いている時よく間違いをする

What happens if I write

> 作文を書いている間によく間違いをする

> 作文を書いている内によく間違いをする

My current best guess is 時 indicates a general point of time, whereas 間 and 内 represent a specific interval, so 時 is more natural here.

Any ideas? My grammar book describes the difference between 間 and うち, but not how it relates to 時.

Comment: What's the difference between "at/when" and "while"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 作文を書いている時(に)よく間違いをする
>
> > When I'm writing an essay, I often make mistakes.

- 時 refers to a **point** in time, the point in time where you're writing.
- に is optional

Using 時 means that the action took place right after, right before, or exactly at that time. In this case, it means 'right after' because you cannot make a mistake before you start writing: context will tell you.

> 作文を書いている間によく間違いをする
>
> > While I'm writing an essay, I often make mistakes.

- 間 refers to a **span of time**, the duration of writing.
- に is **not** optional.

If に is used, it can have two meanings depending on the verb of the main clause. If it's a punctual verb, as in this case 間違いをする, the action took place *instantly* at some point in the span of time marked by 間.

---

In summary, in this case, both sentences mean the same thing, but 時 focuses on a point in time, whereas 間 a span of time, hence the translation:

- When this happens, something often comes true.

Here, 'happens' refers to the point of time where you're writing.

- While this is happening, something often comes true.

'this is happening' refers to a span of time.

---

> 作文を書いている内によく間違いをする
>
> > While I'm writing an essay, I often make mistakes.

- に is a must

This sounds as if making a mistake, while you're writing, is beneficial because of 内に.